# Is there a setting in proget nuget server to make it consider version 1.0.1.0 = 1.0.1

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore, proget

Is there any setting in proget nuget server which can make it treat version `1.0.1.0` = `1.0.1`

So basically when any of the version's package is tried to restore then it will return `1.0.1.0` version's package.

Because I have a package with version `1.0.1.0` in my project but whenever I try to restore it, it always try to look for `1.0.1`, skipping the last zero and so it throws error that the package does not exist. Because proget server has `1.0.1.0` version.

It works when I use my local folder as nuget source in visual studio. Because from local folder it restores the version `1.0.1.0` because it seems for local folder somehow it treats `1.0.1.0` = `1.0.1`

Any idea?

Comment: Please try to [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`

Comment: You used an old nuget cli <= nuget `v 3.3.0` to pack the package 1.0.1.0. Since nuget cli v3.4.4, vs and nuget will ignore the fourth node if it is zero. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#normalized-version-numbers). However, when you uploaded the package on proget, it will still retain the fourth node. So the error occurs

Comment: Hi guy, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a setting in proget nuget server to make it consider version
> 1.0.1.0 = 1.0.1

**ProGet nuget server** does not have an option to make it consider version `1.0.1.0` = `1.0.1`.

I think the package is packed by on old nuget cli `<=v 3.3.0`. And since nuget `v3.4.4`, nuget will remove the fourth node if it is **zero** automatically.

And the latest VS and nuget will ignore the fourth zero node of the package version if you install your package version `1.0.1.0`. See [this official Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#normalized-version-numbers).

So if you install it from local source or `nuget.org`, on these sources, it will remove the last zero from the source path.

**However**, on **ProGet** server(third party nuget server and not **Microsoft**), it still retain the fourth zero node of the package version. So when you install this package on VS, it shows the version `1.0.1.0` in `packages.config` file and when you restore it, it will find version `1.0.1` since the new rule of nuget.

**And** actually, when you enable the ProGet package source, it can still find version `1.0.1.0`. In my side, although it still shows version `1.0.1.0` and vs have to catches `1.0.1` during restore process, the project will still works well.

So I suspect there is some deviation between you and my environment.

**This is my test process:**

**For an example**

This is my package:

[image]

In VS, it shows version `1.0.1`.

[image]

**But**, on **ProGet** nuget server, it shows version `1.0.1.0`.

[image]

**Suggestion**

**First**, try to [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`.

Then enable the proget nuget server package source and remember to check it:

[image]

============================================

If you still face the error, you could follow these below:

**As a suggestion**, you could upload your package on nuget.org, and it will automatically cull your package to version `1.0.1` and then it will synchronize to the **ProGet** nuget server.

When I upload the version `1.0.1.0` on `nuget.org`, it shows version `1.0.1`:

[image]